# Python - Adding offset to time

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have a time string, say

```
str = "2018-09-23 14:46:55"
```

and an offset

```
offset = "0530"
```

I want to get str2 with offset added, ie

```
str2 = "2018-09-23 20:16:55"
```

Please guide.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: This is not a tutorial site. DO your research and make an attempt. Then ask here if something is confusing or giving you issues, and provide sample code. You must help yourself first, then come here for more clarification.

Comment: Yes, i tried. Thanks for enlightening me about format of stackoverflow. Will take care in future. Your answer really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = "2018-09-23 14:46:55"
offset = "0530"

res = datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + \
      timedelta(hours=int(offset[:2]), minutes=int(offset[2:]))

print(res)

datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 23, 20, 16, 55)
```

Comment: Don't know why it was voted down, seems like a perfectly resonable answer....

Answer (score -2):

Use timedelta to add offset to a datetime object.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

str = "2018-09-23 14:46:55"
str = datetime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
str2 = str + timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)

print(str2)
```